# Postgres - Selecting rows begining with value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table in postgres, with a column with int(8) values:

Table TABLE:

```
  number  |   name
----------------------
  1111    |    a
  1122    |    b
  1133    |    c 
  1144    |    d
  1155    |    e
  2211    |    f
  2222    |    g
  2233    |    h
  2244    |    i
  2255    |    k
```

I wanna select all those rows where 'number' begins with "11":

```
  number  |   name
----------------------
  1111    |    a
  1122    |    b
  1133    |    c 
  1144    |    d
  1155    |    e
```

When both columns (number and name) are varchar type, I can compare values using the % operator, like:

```
select *
from TABLE
where number = '11%'
```

But it does not work on int. 
How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with explicit conversion:

```
select *
from TABLE
where cast(number as varchar(255)) like '11%';
```

Be very careful when you write SQL code that does implicit conversion.

Comment: you probably meant to use `like` instead of `=` (although I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name, use `varchar(2)` and `='11'`)

Comment: @paul: `varchar(2)` won't work because the existing values don't fit into that. But I was more referring to the "magic" value 255. There are no optimizations for a `varchar` with length 255 compared to 257, 314 or 42 (in no modern DBMS). Especially in Postgres the length is not needed at all, so a `cast(number as varchar)` or even `cast(number as text)` would make much more sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . It is just a default length that I use for things that should be pretty short.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Today I learned that `convert`ing a `nvarchar(6)` to a `nvarchar(2)` will implicitly truncate, but `convert`ing the integer '123456' to `nvarchar(2)` will overflow...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE number::text LIKE '11%'
```

Comment: Yes, MySQL is pretty sloppy about data type checking.

Answer (score 1):

The column is a number (int), so you should treat it like one.

```
select *
from TABLE
where number >= 1100 and number <= 1199
```

Comment: @gurel_kaynak that value is not in the question, but it could easily be added to the where clause by using OR.

Comment: the question says the number field is int(8). So even 1199999 is in the question. It's not in the example data, but still it's int(8).

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast interger to string and then use like:

```
select * 
from "table" 
where number::text like '11%'
```

Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930361/how-do-i-search-for-a-range-of-integers-in-postgresql)